# Regarding GCP logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Please suggest me a way to get an email notification of all compute engine instances activities once a day
I need to get all the details like when my vm started when it stopped for how much hours it was running

Comment: Google Cloud does not provide those features. You will need either write your own software to parse Cloud Logging or find a third-party product.

Answer (score 1):

**To get the alert when a VM starts or stops, follow the steps below.**

1. Create logs based metrics for VM start.
   Go to console -> Logging -> Logs-based Metrics -> Click on create metric -> Select counter as metric -> Give metric name -> Units as 1.
   Use the following query in the build filter box.
   resource.type="gce_instance"
   protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instances.start"
2. Create logs based metrics for VM stop.
   Follow the same steps mentioned above and use the following query in the build filter box.
   resource.type="gce_instance"
   protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instances.stop"
3. Create Alert Policy and Notification Channel for VM Start alert.
   Go to Monitoring in console -> Click on Alerting -> Create Policy ->  Select resource type as VM Instance -> Select metric created above for start -> At configuration select “any time series violates” as condition trigger, “Is above” as condition, 0 as threshold and “most recent value” as For.
   Click on Next.
   Click on notification channels. If no existing channels then create by clicking on “Manage Notification Channels”. Click email and enter your email address.
4. Repeat the same steps mentioned above to create alert policy and notification Channel for VM Stop alert.
5. You will get an email alert now if you stop and start any VM. To see for which instance you get the notification go to alerting and incidents click on particular policy name.

**To get the alert or to check the running time of the VM.**

1. Click on groups in the monitoring page -> Create group -> Enter group name -> resource type as type and VM Instance as resource type.
2. Go to alerting in the monitoring page ->  Create Policy ->  Select resource type as VM Instance -> Select Uptime Total as metric -> Select Group as filter and select the group created above -> mean as aggregator -> At configuration select “any time series violates” as condition trigger, “Is above” as condition, 0 as threshold and “23hours 30minutes” as For.
3. Click on Next and select Notification Channels.

**Note:** You can directly monitor the running time of a VM by selecting resource type(VM Instance), metric (Uptime Total) and filter (instance_name) in metrics explorer of the monitoring page.

**Reference Links:**
[Log-based-metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics)
[Alerting Policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui)
[Incidents-for-log-based-metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/log-based-incidents)
[Metrics Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer)

Comment: The question asks for an email **once per day**. I do not see that part in your answer.